# GUI for chinese fonts messed up in Android

Tags: android, user-interface

I have an android application which is in english language and the user has the option to switch to chinese language depending on the language of the their phone. The GUI when using english language is okay, but when I switch it to chinese, the GUI gets messed up. Any idea how to have a proper GUI layout when utilizing chinese characters?

[image: Login Activity]

[image: Menu Activity]

Comment: change font size to smaller size in chinese.

Comment: still doesn't work,the buttons got mixed together and the textview also interferes with the edittext

Answer (score 0):

Try using values-zh, raw-zh folders for your text. Font files don't work always. You can use google translate to get the chinese translation of your text and can tweak it if you come across any wrong translation by google.

Comment: Erm, the translation is okay, but the GUI when using the chinese fonts gets messed up, I don't know how to make them align properly.

Answer (score 0):

ACII is messing it up, try Unicode-Encoding. Unicode supports nearly every sign on the world, but keep in mind an ASCII char is 1 Byte, an Unicode takes 2 Bytes!

Comment: I'm using string xml for my chinese characters. How do I go about changing it to unicode encoding

Comment: use <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?> as header